# In Node.js, does setTimeout() block the event loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have a simple setTimeout() function, and set it for 10 seconds...

The the entire server is dead inside those 10 seconds??? Is this true? That's what I heard.

Comment: @voithos then what is this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949465/node-js-how-would-you-recreate-the-settimeout-function-without-it-blocking-th

Comment: Did you read the answers in that link? It's not `setTimeout` that was blocking the event loop, it was the `wait()` function that they implemented. It, literally, just waited the given amount of time (with a while loop, no less)! Of course it would block. `setTimeout` doesn't work that way.

Comment: setTimeout doesn't block anything, just like it doesn't block on the client side. You shouldn't confuse for example PHP's sleep function with setTimeout (or setInterval for that matter).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The answer is **no**. What your link [Node.js: How would you recreate the 'setTimeout' function without it blocking the event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949465/node-js-how-would-you-recreate-the-settimeout-function-without-it-blocking-th) showed was not a `setTimeout` blocking the event loop it was a `while` loop that **deliberately** blocks the event loop. If you want your server to be fast you do not want to block the event loop. An asynchronous callback such as `setTimeout` will work great.

Are you trying to block for some reason (like testing or something?)

Comment: Also, everything above also applies for setInterval.

Answer (score 16):

Another finding that may help others who are learning Node.js and curious of this question, but tricked by a hidden behavior of modern browsers.

The code is really simple, I just want to test my understanding of the "async nature" of Node.js.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("route begin");
    var start = new Date();


    setTimeout(function() {
        res.render('index', { title: start + ' - ' + new Date()});
    }, 20000);//force delay of 20 seconds.

    console.log("route end");
});

module.exports = router;
```

If I start three browser windows(Firefox, more accurately), open the URL defined by this route at the same time, and check the console log from Node.js, it is clear the request **is not handled concurrently**!

I tried the test several times, the results are same.

The typical log output is like this:

```
route begin at: Fri Aug 28 2015 18:35:57 GMT+0800 (CST)
route end at: Fri Aug 28 2015 18:35:57 GMT+0800 (CST)
route begin at: Fri Aug 28 2015 18:36:18 GMT+0800 (CST)
route end at: Fri Aug 28 2015 18:36:18 GMT+0800 (CST)
route begin at: Fri Aug 28 2015 18:36:20 GMT+0800 (CST)
route end at: Fri Aug 28 2015 18:36:20 GMT+0800 (CST)
```

And also, strangely, it was not running in serial mode either(if Node.js is blocked by setTimeout, it should). The interval between the first and second request is 20 seconds, but the second and the third is just 2 seconds.

After scratching my head for quite a while, I suddenly recall that **the browser has a connection limit on the same host**!

So, I quickly setup another test, but this time by issuing multiple curl commands instead.

Hallelujah!

```
route begin at: Fri Aug 28 2015 18:42:51 GMT+0800 (CST)
route end at: Fri Aug 28 2015 18:42:51 GMT+0800 (CST)
route begin at: Fri Aug 28 2015 18:42:53 GMT+0800 (CST)
route end at: Fri Aug 28 2015 18:42:53 GMT+0800 (CST)
route begin at: Fri Aug 28 2015 18:42:55 GMT+0800 (CST)
route end at: Fri Aug 28 2015 18:42:55 GMT+0800 (CST)
```

Comment: Very very very important to note the above!

Comment: I searched for this answer for hours. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

That is not true.  When you call `setTimeout` and return out of your code the server is not blocked.  It is free to process other events (possibly other `setTimeout` callbacks) while waiting for your particular timer to fire

Answer (score 2):

The link which you seem to be confused about does *not* state that `setTimeout` will block. Rather, the OP in that question was trying to make a custom function called `wait` that would behave like `setTimeout`. The `wait` function is the blocking function - `setTimeout` will not block.

Answer (score 1):

The main process seems to be monothreaded by host and blocked by a `setTimeout` or a `while`.

**However, there is an alternative with this code which works as expected and don't block the main process or the event loop:**

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

function setTimeoutAsync (callback, time) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    callback()
  }, time)
  return 0
}

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("route begin")
    var start = +new Date()
    setTimeoutAsync(function () {
      console.log("route done")
      res.json({ delay: ((+new Date()) - start) + 'ms' })
    }, 5000)
    console.log("route end")
});

app.listen(8000)
```

In terminal :

```
route begin // first page
route end
route begin // second page
route end
route begin // third page
route end
route done // first render
route done // second render
route done // third render
```

Good sources:

https://www.journaldev.com/7462/node-js-architecture-single-threaded-event-loop

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/