# node event loop multi threading

Tags: javascript, node.js, multiprocessing, cluster-computing

I am trying to understand how NodeJs multi threading works, as far as I understand NodeJs single-threaded by default. the issue i am having is when user A makes a http request and that requst takes 10 seconds, and right after User B makes a http request, it has to wait for the first request to finish. in other words NodeJs is blocking the event loop.

Code Example:

```
  const sleep = m => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, m));

  app.get("/api/testing", async (req, res) => {
    console.log("\n");
    console.log(
      "******************************************************************"
    );
    console.time("Slept for");
    await sleep(10000);
    res.send("success");
    console.timeEnd("Slept for");
    console.log(
      "******************************************************************"
    );
    console.log("\n");
  });
```

I have tried using cluster module but it didn't work for me, is there a way to make this work without blocking the event loop.

**Update:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32269641/9005749

**After some more research the browser has a connection limit on the same host, once testing on different browsers there is no blocking anymore.**

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. What issue are you facing? What do you have now?

Comment: I don't think thats how node works. Node is all about handling multiple concurrent requests and connections.

Comment: the issue is that the requests are being blocked, they are not happening simultaneously  @Qix

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Node.js, does setTimeout() block the event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950978/in-node-js-does-settimeout-block-the-event-loop)

Comment: @Qix it is helpful and it does answer the question partially, my issue was with Chrome, it has a connection limit on the same host, thats why i thought the event loop was blocked. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32269641/9005749

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be the question marked as a duplicate. Not sure why the close vote window showed a different question when I pasted the link. My comment above was auto-generated :P Glad you found your answer.

Comment: FWIW @publicArt33 most browsers do this. It used to be a constraint in the HTTP/1.1 days but isn't relevant anymore. HTTP/2 does connection multiplexing, I believe some HTTP/1.1 servers and clients support it as well.

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 options

1. Threads https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/worker_threads.html
2. Processes https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/child_process.html

Small but important remark for threads: Unlike processes, transferring handles such as network sockets is currently not supported.

Comment: Please, no. Don't use threads or subprocesses for something such as request handling. This is entirely the point of async engines such as libuv (which powers node.js) - they are able to do asynchronous request handling/sending without the need for multiple threads or processes.